# Post data from controller in Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, web, post

I want to send a $color variable via UserController for editing.

my controller:

```
public function editColor(Color $color)
{
    return view('UserFolder.editColor')->with([

        'color'=>$color,
    ]);
}
```

route:

```
Route::post('admin/EditColors', 'UserController@editColor')->name('editColors');
```

And I get this error:

```
The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.
```

I am not trying to GET that value,is my route isn't correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error sums up everything you are making a `GET` request while your route is defined as `POST` to fix this

Change this:

```
Route::post('admin/EditColors/', 'UserController@editColor')->name('editColors');
```

To:

```
// add {color} parameter to your route what you are expecting in your controller
Route::get('admin/EditColors/{color}', 'UserController@editColor')->name('editColors');
```

Hope it helps..

Thanks..

Comment: So in my view(editColor) I must get the $color with {{$color}}?

Comment: route parameter name should be same as parameter name you passed in function since you are accepting the object of color class as $color so the route parameter name should be {color} without `$` sign..

Comment: happy to help :)